# Python threading - internal buffer error - out of memory

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, out-of-memory, web-crawler, python-multithreading

I made a simple web crawler using urllib and beautifulsoup to extract data from a table on a webpage.  To speed up the data pull I attempted to use threading, but I get the following errors:
"internal buffer error : memory allocation failed : growing buffer"
This message appears quite a few times and then states:
"out of memory"

Thanks for the help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import urllib2
import re
from threading import Thread

stockData = []

#Access the list of stocks to search for data
symbolfile = open("stocks.txt")
symbolslist = symbolfile.read()
newsymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

#text file stock data is stored in
myfile = open("webcrawldata.txt","a")

#initializing data for extraction of web data
lineOfData = ""
i=0

def th(ur):
    stockData = []
    lineOfData = ""
    dataline = ""
    stats = ""
    page = ""
    soup = ""
    i=0
    #creates a timestamp for when program was won
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    #Get Data ONLINE
    #bloomberg stock quotes
    url= "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/" + ur + ":US"
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    #Extract key stats table only
    stats = soup.find("table", {"class": "key_stat_data" })
    #iteration for <tr>
    j = 0
    try:
        for row in stats.findAll('tr'):
            stockData.append(row.find('td'))
            j += 1
        except AttributeError:
            print "Table handling error in HTML"
    k=0
    for cell in stockData:
        #clean up text
        dataline = stockData[k]
        lineOfData = lineOfData + " " + str(dataline)
        k += 1
    g = str(timestamp) + " " + str(ur)+ ' ' + str(lineOfData) + ' ' +  ("\n\n\n")    
    myfile.write(g)
    print (ur + "\n")
    del stockData[:]
    lineOfData = ""
    dataline = ""
    stats = None
    page = None
    soup = None
    i += 1

threadlist = []

for u in newsymbolslist:
    t = Thread(target = th, args = (u,))
    t.start()
    threadlist.append(t)

for b in threadlist:
    b.join()enter code here
```

Comment: How many items do you have in `newsymbolslist`?

Comment: about 2,700 all the NYSE symbols

Comment: So you're starting 2,700 threads in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each thread you start has a thread stack size, which is 8 kb by
default in a Linux system (see `ulimit -s`), so the total number of memory needed for your threads would be more than 20 Gigabytes.

You can use a pool of threads, like for example 10 threads ; when one
has finished its job, it gets another task to do.

But: running more threads than CPU cores is nonsense, in general. So my
advice is to stop using threads. You can use libraries like [gevent](http://www.gevent.org) to
do the exact same thing without using OS-level threads.

The nice thing about gevent is monkey-patching: you can tell [gevent](http://www.gevent.org)
to alter the behaviour of the Python standard library, this will turn your
threads into "greenlet" objects transparently (see [gevent](http://www.gevent.org) documentation
for more details). The kind of concurrency proposed by [gevent](http://www.gevent.org) is
particularly well-suited for intensive I/O as you're doing.

In your code, just add the following at the beginning:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
```

You can't have more than 1024 file descriptors opened at the same time on a
Linux system by default (see `ulimit -n`) so you would have to increase
this limit if you want your 2700 opened file descriptors at the same time.

Comment: Thanks!  I installed gevent and ran as suggested.  It improved the program and it made it much farther into the list than how I had originally coded it.  Although it still ran out of memory and froze.I have been going through the gevent documents to see if I can alter it to stop this.

Comment: You need to understand what is eating memory, exactly. Are you freeing resources properly?

Comment: I don't think so.  Any specific tutorials or examples that would help me do this?  I've been going through this to figure out how to use gevent. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/intro/tutorial.html#intro-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use [`Scrapy` web-scraping framework](http://scrapy.org/):

> Scrapy is an application framework for crawling web sites and
>   extracting structured data which can be used for a wide range of
>   useful applications, like data mining, information processing or
>   historical archival.

Think about it - the scalability/parallelizing/performance problem is **solved for you** - do you really want to continue diving into wonderful world of `Thread`s in python, making your code smell suspiciously, hitting the CPU and memory limits, handling conflicts and, at the end, making your code impossible to debug and maintain - instead of focusing on the extracting and collecting the data? And, even with `gevent` I doubt your final code would be in any ways more simple and readable as the same you would implement based on Scrapy. Why not use the tool that was tested and used by a huge amount of users proven to be the best tool ever created in the web-scraping python world?

Here is a **working** spider that scrapes the quotes in a similar manner:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import Request


class BloombergItem(Item):
    ur = Field()
    parameter = Field()
    value = Field()


class BloombergSpider(Spider):
    name = 'bloomberg'
    allowed_domains = ['www.bloomberg.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        with open("stocks.txt") as f:
            for ur in f:
                yield Request("http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/%s:US" % ur)

    def parse(self, response):
        for parameter in response.css('table.key_stat_data tr'):
            item = BloombergItem()
            item['ur'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[0].split(':')[0]
            item['parameter'] = parameter.xpath('th/text()').extract()[0]
            item['value'] = parameter.xpath('td/text()').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

If the contents of `stocks.txt` is:

```
AAPL
```

The spider would output (for example, if you would choose to output it in JSON):

```
[
  {
    "parameter": "Current P/E Ratio (ttm)",
    "value": "16.6091",
    "ur": "AAPL"
  },
  {
    "parameter": "Estimated P/E(09/2015)",
    "value": "13.6668",
    "ur": "AAPL"
  },
  {
    "parameter": "Relative P/E vs.",
    "value": "0.9439",
    "ur": "AAPL"
  },
  ...
]
```

A good place to start with Scrapy is the [Scrapy Tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/intro/tutorial.html).